# Create matrix with two SQL tables

Tags: sql-server, join, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix which three tables are involved.

Table1 and  Table2 are connected by Key_SK
,Table2 and Table3 are connected by key_FK
,Table2 is the center table which has two keys; key_SK and Key_FK. But there is no key to connect Table1 and Table3:

```
select key_SK, col1,col2,col3
from dbo.table1

select key_SK, key_FK, col3,col4,col5,..
from dbo.table2

select Key_FK,col7,col8,col9,col10
from dbo.table3
```

How can I create a matrix based on these two tables like this:

[image]

Comment: Use PIVOT with a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Please explain with what data the cells of the matrix are supposed to be populated. For example the top left corner (col1, col7). What would be in there? Which table? Which column? Which record? A minimal example with data and expected output would be most helpful.